# How can I imagine double/repeated root of a quadratic equation?

Tags: geometry, roots, quadratics, discriminant

A quadratic equation such as $(x-2)^2=0$ has a repeated root $(2,2)$.
A lot of things in math (equations, matrixes and so) can be nicely drawn on a $2D, 3D$ etc plane (with $x$-$y$ axis).

I mean, I though there is a relation between algebraic equations and geometry, but in this equation, $(x-2)^2$ is a parabola with clearly only one point that lies on an $x$ axis? How could I understand, that there are two roots then?
Also with the imaginary roots I have found ways how to draw it, but it was just something like - how to find the roots with geometry, not something as logical and simple as when a parabola graph penetrates $x$ axis.

Is it because the real result is not exactly a parabola that we can draw on a $x$-$y$ plane or why?

Just for info - I know how to solve it and all the rules, I am really just asking on how to understand it geometrically.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It would be clearer if you said that $(x - 2)^2 = 0$ has a repeated root at $x = 2$.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to understand it imo, is to consider the quadratic *function*

$f(x)=(x-2)^2+c$

Edit: I think it's important to point out here that changing the value of $c$ translates the graph of $f$ vertically.

For small values of  $c<0$. You will notice that there are two roots, but that as $c$ gets closer to $0$ those roots are getting closer not only to each other, but also to the vertex of the parabola. When $c=0$ the roots now coincide, and you have what is known as a double root or repeated root. (This concept can be further generalized for higher degree polynomials and is known as *multiplicity* of a root; it conveys certain information about relative behavior of the graph around the given root.)

If you continue to considering $c>0$, you no longer have real roots, but there are complex numbers which can still satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to interpret (x-2)^2 = 0 as the intersection of y = (x-2)^2 and y = 0. You will find the latter is tangent to the parabola.

You can further imagine that one half of the tangent is running from – infinity towards (2, 0) and the other half is running from the + infinity towards the (2, 0).

Comment: Ok, but in books they say parabola has one vertex. Only one.

Comment: @TomasS The theory is just the same as a straight line touches a circle. They will cut each other at one single point … but when solving the resultant quadratic equation (combined from the linear equation of the straight line and the second degree equation of the circle), we end up with 2 but equal roots. The converse of the above is also true

Comment: The two roots are the same point. That point is the vertex. This is only true for parabolas tangent to the x-axis.

Comment: Also either there is a problem, that the roots are two but we cannot draw it on our 2D plane basically or the vertex is really just one, and the root also, we only cannot describe it with equations in another way than to make two out of it? I get all the facts and can solve it. Its just my couriosity, i just tried it, if there is anyone who was already thinking about it this way and found something interesting. Thanks for answers btw!